# Wso2 keep using wrong assertion url

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to use wso2 SSO. I have set the SP in carbon and set the assertion url like this [image]

Here assertion url is like this `http://example.com/acs`. Now when trying to login on the SSO login screen i keep getting the below message

> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-31 20:14:14,381] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor}
>   -  ALERT: Invalid Assertion Consumer URL value 'http://example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp'
>   in the AuthnRequest message from  the issuer 'simplesaml1'. Possibly
>   an attempt for a spoofing attack

Here `example.com` is same as the domain i used in the image. I have used `example.com` only because stackoverflow doesnt let me add that domain name.

`Can anyone kindly let me know from where wso2 keep reading that url. Its not in metadata also. Also why that url is invalid?` Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This complaint is about that the assertion consumer URL of the SAML **request** is different from the provided URL of the Identity Server. Please check the assertion consumer URL of the SAML **request** from the service provider.

Comment: Looks to me like a configuration issue on simplesaml module. So better to check configs on that side.

Comment: @Jayanga is it possible to change this url `http://example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp`. When i added the url in wso2 it started working. Because previously i set `http://example.com/acs` as the sp assertion url but it was actually set to `http://example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp` in somewhere in simplesamlphp. Hence it was not working. Now its working but i want to change this url. Is it possible?